# How to print content of column consisting of special characters in php

Tags: php, ms-access

In my MS-Access table, there is a column which name consists of spaces and special characters like spaces and slashes. (e.g. E / A / D). I want to print all the rows of it. I thought of this below but I am pretty sure that's wrong.

```
while($row = odbc_fetch_object($result)){
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>$row->E / A / D</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
```

Does anybody know how to do this in the right or more professional way?

Comment: access it with curly braces. like so: `$object->{'my $peci@l column name here'}`

Answer (score 0):

Using curly braces helped.

```
while($row = odbc_fetch_object($result)){
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>$row->{'E / A / D'}</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
```